# less unrecognized input border-radius

Tags: css, less

I just started to learn less. I copied and saved the following code into a file and tried to use lessc to compile it. It gives an error `"ParseError: Unrecognized input"`. I have tried to modify it in many ways and I still could not find the reason. Could anyone please point out what is wrong?

```
.border-radius-custom(@radius:10px) {
    -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
    -moz-border-radius: @radius;
    border-radius: @radius;
}
```

I'm using lessc 2.7.2

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you compile? Your problem is elsewhere since the code itself is fine obviously (expect its supposed to produce an empty result). Note the compiler messages usually point to an exact point of the error ("at line xx column yy") and this information is usually helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine. Below is a demonstration of it working. However, this seems like a compiling error that's likely to do with something else. Do you have any error outputs?

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: #333;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

**What the LESS would look like**

Note: you don't need to specify the pixel width when using the class, that's to demonstrate that you can change it to another value if you want to change it explicitly for one class

```css
.border-radius-custom(@radius:10px) {
    -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
    -moz-border-radius: @radius;
    border-radius: @radius;
}

.container {
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  background:#333;
  .border-radius-custom(10px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... By comparing your code snippet with mine, I found the problem: my less file was saved in utf-8 and included character "C2A0" which looked like spaces in my editor.